# Range lookup in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, search, data-structures

Suppose, I have an unsorted array of overlapped `ranges`. Each `range` is just a pair of integers `begin` and `end`. Now I want to find if a given `key` belongs to at least one of the `ranges`. Probably, I have to know the `ranges` it belongs as well.

We can assume the `ranges` array takes ~1M and fits the memory. I am looking for an easy algorithm, which uses only standard JDK collections without any 3d-party libraries and special data structures, but works reasonably fast.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Are the ranges sorted, or entirely unconstrained?

Comment: I assume linear search won't cut it? There are probably very clever ways to do it, but they'll likely violate your other requirements. Any indication of how many ranges and keys we have?

Comment: I'm unclear on the question, but it sounds like you'll need a hashtable of {key, range} pairs.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. For the key to belong in the range does it have to be between the begin and end? Do you want to find every range the key belongs to? "The ranges may take ~1M". Do you mean the collection of ranges would be ~1M different ranges?

Comment: @ben: It seems more like the question is how to find a `range` for each `key` in the first place. One can of course use a hash table to store it once found, but I don't see how such a hashtable can be constructed without solving OP's problem first.

Comment: @Kerrek the ranges are not sorted

Comment: @delnan we probably have ~10^5 ranges and many-many keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to know *which* interval contains your point (EDIT: I guess you probably do, but I'll leave this answer for others with this question who don't), then

1. Preprocess the intervals by computing two arrays B and E. B is the values of begin in sorted order. E is the values of end in sorted order.
2. To query a point x, use binary search to find the least index i such that B[i] > x and the least index j such that E[j] ≥ x. The number of intervals [begin, end] containing x is i - j.

---

```
class Interval {
    double begin, end;
}

class BeginComparator implements java.util.Comparator<Interval> {
    public int compare(Interval o1, Interval o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.begin, o2.begin);
    }
};

public class IntervalTree {
    IntervalTree(Interval[] intervals_) {
        intervals = intervals_.clone();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(intervals, new BeginComparator());
        maxEnd = new double[intervals.length];
        initializeMaxEnd(0, intervals.length);
    }

    double initializeMaxEnd(int a, int b) {
        if (a >= b) {
            return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        int m = (a + b) >>> 1;
        maxEnd[m] = initializeMaxEnd(a, m);
        return Math.max(Math.max(maxEnd[m], intervals[m].end), initializeMaxEnd(m + 1, b));
    }

    void findContainingIntervals(double x, int a, int b, java.util.Collection<Interval> result) {
        if (a >= b) {
            return;
        }
        int m = (a + b) >>> 1;
        Interval i = intervals[m];
        if (x < i.begin) {
            findContainingIntervals(x, a, m, result);
        } else {
            if (x <= i.end) {
                result.add(i);
            }
            if (maxEnd[m] >= x) {
                findContainingIntervals(x, a, m, result);
            }
            findContainingIntervals(x, m + 1, b, result);
        }
    }

    java.util.Collection<Interval> findContainingIntervals(double x) {
        java.util.Collection<Interval> result  = new java.util.ArrayList<Interval>();
        findContainingIntervals(x, 0, intervals.length, result);
        return result;
    }

    Interval[] intervals;
    double[] maxEnd;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
        Interval[] intervals = new Interval[10000];
        for (int j = 0; j < intervals.length; j++) {
            Interval i = new Interval();
            do {
                i.begin = r.nextDouble();
                i.end = r.nextDouble();
            } while (i.begin >= i.end);
            intervals[j] = i;
        }
        IntervalTree it = new IntervalTree(intervals);
        double x = r.nextDouble();
        java.util.Collection<Interval> result = it.findContainingIntervals(x);
        int count = 0;
        for (Interval i : intervals) {
            if (i.begin <= x && x <= i.end) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.size());
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! What if I want to know _which_ intervals contain the point?

Comment: @Michael Convert the algorithm in CLRS (as described in the Wikipedia page on interval trees) to use an array rather than a binary tree. I have to go now, but I'll post details in a while if no one else does first.

Comment: @Michael Java code added. Consider it WTFPL licensed in case StackOverflow hasn't already claimed it for Aiur. `maxEnd[m]` contains the maximum value of end among `intervals[a], ..., intervals[m - 1]`.

Comment: thanks for mentioning Wikipedia page on interval trees!

Answer (score 5):

Sort the ranges numerically by a custom `Comparator`, then for each key *k* build a one-element range [*k*, *k*] and do a [binary search](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) for this range with a different `Comparator`.

The `Comparator` for searching's `compare(x,y)` should return

- `<0` if `x.max < y.min`
- `>0` if `x.min > y.max`
- `0` otherwise (its two range arguments overlap).

As noted by @Per, you need a different, stricter `Comparator` for sorting, but the first two clauses still hold.

This should work even if the ranges overlap, though you may want to merge overlapping ranges after sorting to speed up the search. The merging can be done in O(*N*) time.

This is in effect a static [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), i.e. one without O(lg *N*) insertion or deletion, in the same way that a sorted array can be considered a static binary search tree.

Comment: Sounds good! How would suggest sort the `ranges`? By `begin` or by `end`?

Comment: Exactly what does your `Comparator` do? I'm skeptical that this approach can be made work for overlapping intervals – the standard interval tree has two sorted lists for the intervals overlapping each split point, and the data structure described in CLRS needs to augment the tree (which is sorted by left endpoints) by the max right endpoint in each subtree.

Comment: @Michael: expanded the answer.

Comment: That choice of `Comparator` has non-transitive `equals`, which breaks the `Comparator` contract. Even if `sort` somehow manages to return an array consistent with the irreflexive transitive relation you've defined, binary search won't work. We could have a sorted array with intervals …, [2, 4], [0, 3], … and then a binary search that starts by comparing [1, 1] against [2, 4] will proceed to the wrong half.

Comment: Oh, the `equals` method doesn't do what I thought it did. To clarify: the `compare` function is non-transitive in the sense that `compare(x,y) == 0 && compare(y,z) == 0` does not imply that `compare(x,z) == 0`.

Comment: @Per: you're right that it won't work for sorting, but I don't get the remark about searching not working.

Comment: @larsmans If the sort arranges overlapping intervals maliciously, then binary search can fail. In my example, it compares [1, 1] against [2, 4], finds it to be less, and then fruitlessly searches the left half of the array. [0, 3] can be to the right of [2, 4] because those intervals overlap.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

But check this simpler solution first to see if it fits your needs: [Using java map for range searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314650/using-java-map-for-range-searches)

Answer (score 1):

simple solution with O(n) complexity:

```
for(Range range: ranges){
  if (key >= range.start && key <= range.end)
    return range;
}
```

More clever algorithm can be applied if we know more information about ranges.
Is they sorted? Is they overlapped? and so on

Answer (score 1):

Given just your specification, I would be inclined to order the ranges by size, with the widest ranges first (use a custom Comparator to facilitate this).  Then simply iterate through them and return true as soon as you find a range that contains the key.  Because we know nothing else about the data, of course the widest ranges are the most likely to contain a given key; searching them first could be a (small) optimization.

You could preprocess the list in other ways.  For instance, you could exclude any ranges that are completely enclosed by other ranges.  You could order by `begin` and early-exit as soon as you encounter a `begin` value greater than your key.