# How to store a range of int pairs in a map

Tags: java

I have code where I need to store a range of y-y and z-z co-ordinates as one single key to a HashMap.

Currently, I'm iterating through every y and z co-ordinate; wrapping them in a Tuple and then saving that Tuple as a key to a designated value. This, however, doesn't seem efficient to me as memory usage can become a problem.

Let's say I have a y range of between 50-100 and the z range also 50-100. Is it possible to store the y and z ranges and as a valid example (75,75) retrieve the value mapped to ranges? 101,101 would be an invalid example.

Finally, I also need to prevent the key pair overlapping with either x or z.

If anyone could help me with this it would be much appreciated as I am puzzled.

Regards

Comment: can you give example of some key/value pairs ? Not sure to understand

Comment: Please give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't get what you're trying to do from the description

Comment: @azro The key would be `new Tuple(new Range(25, 75), new Range(25, 75))` for example and a value will be any object. I want to be able to retrieve value from the key of that of two given ints that are in range of both the values in Tuple class without having to use direct iteration

Comment: You lay use iteration, because for Map you need equality to get back a value from the key, in fact give the same Tuple with same Range, but this is clearly not what you wan't to do, you want to give 2 ints in both Range, you may proper iteration (or Stream),

Comment: The problem with iteration is performance for me.

Comment: You asked a question, some answers, by respect you may think about accept or vote up answer for those who spent time for you

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for an [IntervalTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

I posted an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11189080/823393) a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

I made some suppositions from your implementation :

```
public class Range {    
    private final int from;    
    private final int to;
}
// - - AND - - 
public class Tuple {    
    private final Range rf;    
    private final Range rt;
}
```

I propose to add the following methods :

```
// In Range class
public boolean isValid(int x) {
     return (from <= x) && (x <= to);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// In Tuple class
public boolean isValid(int x, int y) {
     return rf.isValid(x) && rf.isValid(y);
}
```

And a class to manage your stuff :

```
public class TupleGestion {   
    private static final Map<Tuple, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    private static String getValue(int x, int y) {

        return map.get(map.keySet().stream()
                          .filter(key -> key.isValid(x, y)).findAny().orElse(null));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        map.put(new Tuple(new Range(25, 75), new Range(25, 75)), "foo");

        System.out.println(getValue(0, 0));    // null
        System.out.println(getValue(50, 0));   // null
        System.out.println(getValue(0, 50));   // null
        System.out.println(getValue(50, 50));  // foo
    }

}
```

This will read over the key and find one which correspond to your attemp, have the 2 `ints` into both range

---

*EDIT - Performance :*

- add 6000 random elements in the map  : `<5ms`
- use `nanoTime()` to compute the time it takes for use `getValue()` :

  - only `getValue()` for 20000 times : `100ms< t < 150ms`
  - `System.out.println(getValue())` 20000 times : `850ms< t <1sec`

You were asking about 3000 elements and 1000 `getValue()` : `<5ms` (200 times lower than 1sec)

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going for. Would this be good performance rise though?; as I need to run this at least 1000 times a second with lots of objects in the map.

Comment: about how many object in the Map ? I'll try and tell you the time to get 1000 values

Comment: There are about 3000

Comment: I've edit, with 20 times elements than you ask, and 2 times more elements in the map ;)