# Structure to use for between values - something like a HashMap

Tags: java, android

I want to know what will be best to use if I have something like chapters with pages from-to - example:

```
Chapter 1, 0-10;
Chapter 2, 11-33;
Chapter 3, 54-90;
...
```

Now I want to get the chapter based on the on a page number, in example I input `60`, and it should return `Chapter 3`.

How can I do this in JAVA?

Comment: Use a `NavigableMap`, and the `floorKey()` method: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/treemap_floorkey.htm

Comment: Depends on your principal requirement, speed or memory cost. For absolute speed, a simple HashMap with every page as a key and their chapter as the value would be best.

Comment: Use `TreeMap` look at answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314650/using-java-map-for-range-searches

Comment: Darko If you need something that works check my answer.

Comment: @Darko Petkovski - Are they continues page number for chapters? LIke, for Chapter 3 its should be 34 not 54 ??

Comment: Do you want the hashmap to return a string or an integer Darko

Comment: These hashmaps are just name value pairs darko.  You can make them however you want.  If you want 34 to return chapter 3.  Its as simple as this chapters.put(34, "Chapter3");  now you can change the chapters to ints if you want I just thought I would make it simple to understand.

Comment: @Xjasz I want an interger returned

Comment: Changed answer try it out

Comment: @Kon your comment gave me the answer, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could make a hash map of Integers that return a String for the chapter you are on

```
private void SimpleChapterHashmap(){
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> chapters = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        chapters.put(i, 1);
    }
    for (int i = 11; i < 33; i++) {
        chapters.put(i, 2);
    }
    for (int i = 34; i < 90; i++) {
        chapters.put(i, 3);
    }

    Log.d("CHAPTER", chapters.get(60));
}
```

Comment: Its just an example this isn't something that oracle needs.

Comment: @Xjasz See my comment above for a MUCH better, MUCH more efficient implementation which is already part of the Java API

Comment: Your link is no different other than using <Integer,Integer>

Comment: I think the reason people are saying it's inefficient is not because you used `String` but because you stored an entry for every page rather than every chapter. All the other people commenting have assumed the `54` in the question was a typo, and that you could use a `TreeMap` to just store the last page number for each chapter. In fairness, your answer does answer the question as given.

Comment: I was only using a String to help him understand it a little better.  Of course you can use integer,integer or even range,integer but that might make it harder for someone to understand.