# What datatype to use in Java to match interval?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a list of objects that implement non-overlapping ranges, e.g.:

```
1 to 10
11 to 20
21 to 50
51 to 100
```

They provide `min()` and `max()` to retrieve those values.

I need a datastore to easily retrieve the right object, given a value that must be in its interval.

The easiest way I can think of is to create an ordered arraylist and simply traverse it until I found the correct interval. So in this case a lookup is done in O(N).

Are there more efficient data structures available in the standard Java library to do this task?

Comment: Well binary search takes O(log n)

Comment: Yes, but is there a standard datastructure in java that fulfills this requirement?

Comment: Does your object implement Comparable interface, comparing on that field? What does your object look like?

Comment: I maintain class of that object myself, so I can add anything I want

Comment: How about [Arrays.binarySearch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the `NavigableMap`, that method is explained in this answer: [Using java map for range searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314650/using-java-map-for-range-searches), the 'no holes' aproach.

Example implementation using TreeMap:

```
// Create TreeMap
NavigableMap<Integer, MyInterval> map = new TreeMap<>();

// Putting values
map.put(interval1.min(), myInterval);
map.put(interval2.min(), myInterval);

// Retrieving values
int value = 15;
MyInterval interval = map.floorEntry(value).getValue();

// Check if value is smaller than max()
if (value <= interval.max())
    return interval;
return null;
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to reinvent the wheel, [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides the [`Range`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html), [`RangeSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html), and [`RangeMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) classes.  See the [Ranges Explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained) docs for more details.

Comment: While this may be a good solution, I was asking for a standard Java data structure.

Comment: `NavigableMap` is also very useful, but limiting yourself to "standard" data structures is an unnecessary impedance.  No modern Java codebase is complete without Guava (and much of Guava made its way into Java 8).

Comment: I'm customizing an ERP system. Adding extra libraries is not trivial for me, that's why I will only resort to this if I really have to.